# I'm curious about apple homepage

Tags: web, browser

Apple several websites have several scroll animations and I've found out that some devices do not work with the animation.

So I'm wondering, is Apple show the animation only that devices have enough performance for animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple Uses a in-house framework named Apple JS.i think whit this framework, scroll animation is identical over Apple's web site.